# Room new feature Auto Migration error: incompatible type cannot be converted to List<Migration>

Tags: android, android-room, auto-migration

I tried to use Room Auto Migration feature ([introduced here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/AutoMigration?hl=ru)) But this doesn't work when I try to create auto test. So, I added to TaskEntity new Category column

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
data class TaskEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val shortDescription: String,
    val fullDescription: String,
    val deadline: Date?,
    // This is new column
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "DEFAULT")
    val category: TaskCategory
)

enum class TaskCategory {
    WORK, SPORT, SHOPPING, EDUCATION, DEFAULT
}
```

After this I updated Database like this:

```
@Database(
    version = 3,
    entities = [TaskEntity::class],
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 2, to = 3)],
    exportSchema = true
)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
abstract class ToDoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {

        fun newTestDatabase(context: Context) = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context,
            ToDoDatabase::class.java
        )
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build()
    }

    abstract fun tasks(): TodoDao
}
```

Where 3 - is new version, and AutoMigration(from = 2, to = 3) is new Auto Migration

My Old migration

```
@VisibleForTesting
internal val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tasks ADD COLUMN deadline INT")
    }
}
```

When I run androidTest, I got such error:

```
error: incompatible types: List<ToDoDatabase_AutoMigration_2_3_Impl> cannot be converted to List<Migration>
    return Arrays.asList(new ToDoDatabase_AutoMigration_2_3_Impl());
```

My androidTest looks like:

```
@Test
fun test2To3() {
    // Create database with old version 2
    val initialDb = migrationTestHelper.createDatabase(DB_NAME, 2)

    // Insert task

    initialDb.execSQL(
        "INSERT INTO tasks (id, title,  shortDescription,  fullDescription, deadline) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?)",
        arrayOf(
            TEST_ID,
            TEST_TITLE,
            TEST_SHORT_TEXT,
            TEST_FULL_TEXT,
            Calendar.getInstance().time
        )
    )

    // Check that task inserted
    initialDb.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks").use {
        assertThat(it.count, equalTo(1))
        it.moveToFirst()
        assertThat(it.getInt(0), equalTo(1))
    }

    // Close DB
    initialDb.close()

    // Run auto migration
    val db = migrationTestHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate(
        DB_NAME,
        3,
        true
    )

    // Check data
    db.query("SELECT id, title, shortDescription, fullDescription, deadline FROM tasks")
        .use {
            assertThat(it.count, equalTo(1))
            it.moveToFirst()
            assertThat(it.getInt(0), equalTo(TEST_ID))
            assertThat(it.getString(1), equalTo(TEST_TITLE))
            assertThat(it.getString(2), equalTo(TEST_SHORT_TEXT))
            assertThat(it.getString(3), equalTo(TEST_FULL_TEXT))
            assertThat(it.getString(5),  equalTo("DEFAULT"))
        }
}
```

}

Also the question is, what should I add to the migrationTestHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate ? I tried this

```
val db = migrationTestHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate(
    DB_NAME,
    3,
    true,
    ToDoDatabase_AutoMigration_2_3_Impl()
)
```

I added ToDoDatabase_AutoMigration_2_3_Impl() but still doesn't work. When I used manual migration this looked like this:

```
val db = migrationTestHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate(
    DB_NAME,
    2,
    true,
    MIGRATION_1_2
)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: As a workaround, you could add a second Automigration from version 1 to 2 and the error goes away. There seems to be a bug which only occurs when one Automigration is added.

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug